# How we can call URLGetCombinedData in java using Alchemy API with different parameters?

Tags: java, alchemyapi, alchemy

I am using Alchemy API for my project. I want to call a method URLGetCombinedData with different parameter. By default it has four parameter i.e concepts, entity, taxonomy and keyword. But i want to call other parameters like author, relation etc. So please help me in calling all the parameters in one call. I am using JAVA SDK.

Regards and Thanks in advance